# Maximum of sum of iid random variable with two outcomes, threshold crossing

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be the sum of n iid random variables, and $M_N$ be $\max_{n\leq N} S_n$.

I know that given it is a simple random walk, i.e. $X_i=-1$ with probability $p$ and $-1$ with probability $1-p$, the probability of crossing a threshold $\mathbb{P}(M_N>c)$ can be calculated in closed form.

In general if we have a random variable $X_i$ with two outcomes not necessarily $-1$ and $1$, say $-1$ with probability $p$ and $8$ with probability $1-p$, is $\mathbb{P}(M_N>c)$ (equality, NOT inequality) still under closed form?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You looking expected value or the new distribution? And a sum of any specific distributions?

Comment: You define $M_n = \max_{n \leq N} S_n$ but there is likely a typo since $N$ appears nowhere, and the left-hand-side is a function of $n$, the right-hand-side I cannot interpret. I also do not understand your last sentence.

Comment: @Michael is it clear now?

Comment: @cmitch I am looking for the probability of crossing a threshold.